# Any sample code on getting data from sensors on Mac?

Tags: cocoa, macos

I am a newbie to Objective-C and this site, so can you point me in the right direction?
I need sample code on **ambient light sensor** and **sudden motion sensor** on *Mac*. I really need this code and I didn't find anything on google. Can anyone help please?

Comment: Ignore the duplicate vote, as the question was changed and I didn't refresh before voting.

Comment: thanks for editing tags. I totally forgot about them...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Amit Singh's *Mac OS X Internals* site has info about the [sudden motion sensor](https://web.archive.org/web/20200103161737/http://osxbook.com/book/bonus/chapter10/sms/) and the [ambient light sensor](https://web.archive.org/web/20200103164052/https://osxbook.com/book/bonus/chapter10/light/).

Here's a [library](https://web.archive.org/web/20210305170839/http://www.suitable.com/tools/smslib.html) for getting the motion sensor data.

Comment: Thanks for the motion sensor library, but the code for ambient light sensor isn't working on 10.5+