# Access Ambient Light Sensor on Mac

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Any sample code on getting data from sensors on Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628547/any-sample-code-on-getting-data-from-sensors-on-mac)

Is it possible to access the ambient light sensor to use in cocoa applications and if so would apple allow this?

I have seen that [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20200103164052/https://osxbook.com/book/bonus/chapter10/light/) would work without using private API but other stacked question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628547/any-sample-code-on-getting-data-from-sensors-on-mac) claims it has stopped working for mac 10.5 +  Has anyone looked into how to do this? Thanks

Comment: thanks for the reference, are those are all private API's?

Comment: retagged, previous tag 'iOS' did not fit for this question